# Java Program and YouTube API

Tags: java, youtube-api

I'm trying to write a program that checks if a user uploaded a new video. I wanted to make it a backend job that constantly checks a users most recent video and then send a push my users utilizing my application. Is there any documentation or sample code on this matter? I haven't the slightest clue where to start.

Comment: how is this related to ios?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found is via RSS feed. Simple to parse. Simple to get it going. Begin checking this out:
https://www.youtube.com/t/rss_feeds

To PARSE the RSS in java, use Rome: https://github.com/rometools/rome

Answer (score 0):

Download YouTube's [Java API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) and then use the code they provide:

```
String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads";

VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);
```

This is for version 3, which is the latest they provide.

Comment: I thought that had been deprecated, no? Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information.